# why is it showing stringoutofbounds exception while i am only comparing the 0th index of two strings?

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I was doing a leetcode problem and I got a `String index out of range: 0 exception` for the below code:

```java
    public boolean isInterleave(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
        int n = 0;
        int m = 0;
            
        if (s1.charAt(0) == s3.charAt(0)) {
            n++;

            for (int j = 1; j < s1.length(); j++) {
                if (s1.charAt(j) == s3.charAt(j)) {
                    n++;                        
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < s2.length(); j++) {
                if (s2.charAt(j) == s3.charAt(j + n)) {
                    m++;                        
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (n > 0) {
            System.out.println(n);
        } else {
            System.out.println(m);
        }
    }
```

I tried to count how many characters of two strings are the same for a string like in the problem of interleaving String question and expected to print `2,2` for the
input `s1 = "aabcc", s2 = "dbbca", s3 = "aadbbcbcac"`

Comment: Index 0 is out of bounds for an empty string.  You need to check for that first.

Comment: Your error message is telling you the reason: the string has length of 0. There is no 0th element.

Comment: Or maybe you don't need to special-case the `s1.charAt(0) == s3.charAt(0)` comparison in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Te why, is because an empty string does not have a char at position 0, but you just don't need that first if.

The first for loop will not enter if the string `s1` is empty but the second will.

You could add a `if` before that for checking for emptyness, but I don't know what you should return in that case, something like this:

```java
public boolean isInterleave(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
    if (s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty() || s3.isEmpty() {
        return ...; //what's appropriate for this case
    }
... //your code.
}
```

I'm not saying this is what you should do to resolve your problem, just how to avoid the error you are having and as a form of exemplifying why you are having it.

Answer (score 0):

> *"why is it showing stringoutofbounds exception while i am only comparing the 0th index of two strings? ..."*

If I run this code with the *[Interleaving String](https://leetcode.com/problems/interleaving-string/)* problem on *LeetCode*, I get the following error.

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
  at line 48, java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt
  at line 1513, java.base/java.lang.String.charAt
  at line 6, Solution.isInterleave
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 90, __Driver__.main
```

Line 6 is,

```java
if (s1.charAt(0) == s3.charAt(0))
```

In situations where *s1* or *s3* are empty, the *[String#charAt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))* method will throw an *IndexOutOfBoundsException*, which is the parent class of *[StringIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)*.

Here is the *String#charAt* *JavaDoc*,

> **Throws:**
>
> [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) - if the index argument is negative or not less than the length of this string.

You'll have to check both *s1* and *s3* for content.
I'm using the *[String#isEmpty](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())* method here, which checks *[String#length](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#length())* for 0.

```java
if ((!s1.isEmpty() && !s3.isEmpty()) && s1.charAt(0) == s3.charAt(0))
```

This should get you to the next step in the process.